# Updating a sql column by 1 when value is in a temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to add 1 to a column if the value of another column in the same row is equal to a value in a temp table. Below is the code. When I run the code from a store procedure it adds 1 to every column, not just the ones that show up in the temp table. Does anyone see anything wrong with the query?

```
DECLARE @LineTable TABLE (
TempLineNumber FLOAT)


INSERT @LineTable
SELECT DocumentNumber
FROM   chargebackdetailtemptable
GROUP  BY DocumentNumber
HAVING Count(*) > 1

UPDATE ChargebackDetailTempTable
SET    LineNumber = (SELECT Max(LineNumber) + 1
                     FROM   ChargebackDetailTempTable c
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN @LineTable c2
                              ON c.DocumentNumber = c2.TempLineNumber
                     WHERE  c.DocumentNumber IS NOT NULL
                            AND c2.TempLineNumber IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: That's beacuse you're updating all rows with the same `max(LineNumber) + 1`; you haven't specified any `WHERE` criteria.

Comment: There is WHERE criteria in the query, do I need to move it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE ChargebackDetailTempTable
SET LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
FROM ChargebackDetailTempTable
INNER JOIN @LineTable lt ON lt.DocumentNumber = ChargebackDetailTempTable.DocumentNumber
WHERE lt.DocumentNumber IS NOT NULL
```

You can use joins in update statements.  I wasn't sure if you were +1'ing the line number or something from `lt` (aliased as `c2` in your subquery in the question above).  Either way, this should get you where you want to be.

Comment: Where should I put the "where" clause in that update statement, Eli? I need only the records that are not null in the temp table to be +1

Comment: after the `inner join`.  If you have a one-for-one relationship between `ChargeBack` and `@LineTable` (meaning `DocumentNumber` is unique in both) then `WHERE lt.DocumentNumber IS NOT NULL`.  Updated my post as an example.  However, don't you think it's easier to NOT INSERT the documents you don't want into the temp table than forcing a filter on the update? i.e. pre-filter the temp table before doing the update.